# A person tile can be marked as read?

Tags: tiles

I have a tile with my wife's profile. When she say something in Facebook (for example) the tile starts to show in its back what she said.

I go to her profile and click the status. I read it and go back. I go to "What's new" to see the same thing and open it again.

After that I go to home screen by pression back button. The tile still show the notification and looks like is impossible to stop it.

In "Me" tile when I read the notification it stops to show in back tile.

Edit:
My Phone is a Samsung Focus

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a typo. In the question I mean "tile" and no "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot mark the tile's status update as "read".  The status update will continue to display until somewhere between 12 and 24 hours have passed from the time the event (status update, photo posted, ect).

Comment: @Brian-P-Hamachek I think you are not completely right. I made a test and one tile stops to show after 12 hours. But your answer was the closer.

Answer (score 2):

> In "Me" tile when I read the notification it stops to show in back tile.

If you open the `Me` tile and wait for it to sync, everything will be considered "read". You can see the progress-bar in the top.

Facebook posts are considered read as well, if you read them on Facebook website or with the Facebook App. Twitter posts are considered read when the sync is done.

Comment: Ok, in "Me" tile I don't have a problem. The problem is when my wife's tile gets updates. Even tough I open all the profile and the "What's new" (and wait to sync) it keeps to show the status. Right now I have in that tile her update made 12h ago and never stops it to show.

Comment: That's working as intended. In my experience, It will automatically stop after a period.

Comment: I think it needs to work like "Me" tile. When I open and wait to sync it is "marked as read". I think other tile need the same behavior. But they don't.

Comment: @VitorCanova feel free to push for the feature on the WP uservoice site http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions